# Find a singular value decomposition of the matrix...

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A =   \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 2  \\
        -1 & 1  \\
        2 & -2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

I'm getting eigenvalues of $18$ and $0$, so I'm not sure how to proceed with an eigenvalue of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is rank one matrix, so the svd id $a=18 uv^t $ where $u=(2,1,- 2)^t÷3, v=(- 1,1)^t÷sqrt (2) $

Comment: Thank you, I've been able to solve for a and v, as well as the first column vector of u, but I'm still not sure how to get u2 and u3

Comment: @sse For the columns of $U$ find the eigenvectors of $AA^T$

Answer (score 0):

The singular values of $A$ are the are the square roots of the $\text{nonzero}$ eigenvalues of $A^TA$. In this case you found that the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are $0$ and $18$ so the only singular value is $\sqrt{18}$.

To find the matrix $V$, find an eigenvector for $A^TA$ and normalize it. In this case $$A^TA=\begin{pmatrix} 9 & -9 \\ -9 & 9  \end{pmatrix}$$
For the eigenvalue $\lambda=18$ I found a normalized eigenvector of $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. For $\lambda=0$ I found an eigenvector of $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and so $$V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}.$$ $\Sigma$ is the $3\times 2$ matrix whose diagonal is composed of the singular values $$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{18} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0&0  \end{pmatrix}.$$ Finally $AV=U\Sigma$ and the colums of $U$ are the eigenvectors of $AA^T$, solving this system of equations you get that $$U=\frac 13\begin{pmatrix} 2 & \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 1 & 0 & \sqrt{8} \\ -2& \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}.$$